# ¿Como ejecutar una funcion UseEffect antes de renderizar del RETURN() en REACT?

Tags: array

Soy nuevo en React y estoy intentando renderizar un componente solo cuando un tamaño de un JSON que traigo desde una API a traves de UseEffect sea mayor a 0, pero siempre me ejecuta primero el return() del componente y después me ejecuta el UseEffect siendo que lo que necesito es alreves.

Este es el codigo del componente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getFacturas} from '../services/getFacturas'




const Facturas = ({ rut }) => {
  const [misFacturas, setmisFacturas] = useState([]);

  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {

      const response = await getFacturas(rut);


      if (response.result.length > 0) {
        setFlag(true);
        setmisFacturas(response.result);

      }
      else {
        setFlag(false);
      }


    })();


  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {flag == false ? (
           console.log(" NO TIENE FACTURAS")
      ) : (
        ''
      )
      }
      
      {flag == true ? (

       console.log("TIENE FACTURAS")

      ) : (
         ''
        
      )

      }
    </>
  );
};


export default Facturas;
```

El problema es que SIEMPRE cae primero al flag = false y luego al true en el caso de que fuera true, es como si se ejecutara 2 veces el useEffect siendo que necesito que entre solo a 1 y una sola vez cuando carga la pagina.

Quizás hay algún concepto que no estoy usando correctamente.

Estaría muy agradecido de cualquier aporte

Saludos Cordiales y feliz navidad a todos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de solucionar tu problema en específico. Pero también sería bueno aclarar algunos conceptos, porque dices:

> El problema es que SIEMPRE cae primero al flag = false y luego al true en el caso de que fuera true

A simple vista eso no es un "problema", es un hecho. Porque estás definiendo `const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)`. SIEMPRE `flag` va a ser primero `false`.

Parece que el `response.result` es un `Array`. Entonces puedes hacer algo como:

1. Crear un estado `isLoading` => `true` por defecto.
2. Utilizar dicho estado en el `useEffect` antes y después de recibir las facturas.
3. Siempre que `isLoading` sea `true` desplegar un mensaje.
4. De lo contrario comprobar el `length` de `misFacturas`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getFacturas } from '../services/getFacturas'


const Facturas = ({ rut }) => {
  const [misFacturas, setmisFacturas] = useState([]);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const response = await getFacturas(rut);
      setmisFacturas(response.result);
      setIsLoading(true)
    })();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <>Cargando...</>

  return (
    <>
      {misFacturas.length === 0 && (
        console.log(" NO TIENE FACTURAS")
      )}
      
      {misFacturas.length > 0 && (
       console.log("TIENE FACTURAS")
      )}
    </>
  );
};


export default Facturas;
```

Comment: Funciono Perfectamente estimado muy bien explicado hasta pude ponerle el componente del cargador que tenia ya hecho Muchas Gracias @jonoise!!!!!

Comment: @pabloastudillo me alegro que te haya funcionado. considera votar positivamente la respuesta y aceptarla como correcta. :)